# How to make Chrome Apps appear in dock/status bar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

If you have ever used the Google Hangouts chrome app you can see that an icon is added to the status bar (not sure if status bar is the correct name).

[image]

Is there an api for this? how can I make my chrome app appear over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to include a [native client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/) plugin with your chrome app. There's not much [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) about this on the Chrome developer site, as they're phasing out the original plugin architecture (NPAPI).

There's some specific documentation on including these types of plugins in a Chrome app [here](https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/devguide/distributing#distributing-packaged).

Comment: This is how the hangouts app does it, but note that Chrome is dropping support for NPAPI plugins.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your app its icon appears on the status or task bar. Right click the icon and pin it to the bar.